# Add distinguishing letter to citation with same author and year

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

When I use natbib with [named.bst](https://www.ee.iitb.ac.in/%7Etrivedi/LatexHelp/BSTfiles/named.bst), citations with the same author and year are distinguished in the text, but not in the bibliography.

[image]

I would like the bibliography to say "2022a" and "2022b" as in the text. Is it possible? Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep{Doe1,Doe2}

\bibliographystyle{named}
\bibliography{main}

\end{document}
```

and for main.bib:

```
@misc{Doe1,
    author = {John Doe},
    title = {Article 1},
    year = {2022}
}

@misc{Doe2,
    author = {John Doe},
    title = {Article 2},
    year = {2022}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Any chance you could use a bibliography style other than `named`, which hasn't been supported since 1988?

Comment: @Mico Unfortunately, using "named" is part of the template I am required to use :(

Comment: If you must use the `named` style, you’re not allowed to modify the `named` style either, right?

Comment: @Mico Modifying "named" slightly should be ok. Is there a way to fix the problem by doing so?

Comment: It seems odd that your publisher would tolerate modifications being made to `named`. FWIW, the output of the `named` bib style is pretty much identical to that of the `plainnat` style, *except* that the latter style produces the desired letter suffixes for publications with the same authors and publication year. I'd change `\usepackage{natbib}` to `\usepackage[square]{natbib}` (the `square` option tells natbib to use square brackets rather than round parentheses in citation call-outs), I'd replace  `\bibliographystyle{named}`  with `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`, and wait if anyone notices.